# Firebase real time database offline persistence using Maui.net

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, maui, offline-caching, data-persistence

Does FirebaseDatabase.net support offline persistance with maui.net?
if so, could someone give me a snipit of what i need to do.
If not, does anyone have any suggestions or examples that show how to achieve this?

Thanks,

I'm using FirebaseDatabase.net (nugget package)

I have searched and cannot find any examples or discusion on this using Maui.net

Answer (score 0):

From the [`step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet` repro](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet):

> Simple wrapper on top of Firebase Realtime Database REST API.

This means that any caching would have to implemented inside that library itself, and from a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/src/Firebase/FirebaseClient.cs) it doesn't seem to have any caching.

Comment: I had to sync a local sqlite database to try and maintain offline capabilities.  However this is no a trivial task just subscribing and without frequently comparing databases (pulling the entire database from firebase).   I believe the APIs for just about everything but .net have an offline persistence capability.  If anyone has a more practical solution then , please enlighten me.

Comment: The official SDKs that Firebase provides for client-side apps indeed having caching built in. The one you use is not one of those, and (like most third-party clients that wrap the REST API) does not implement caching.